# Read a excel file data for a html dropdown in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I have a dropdown in my html page, for this dropdown I am trying to  pick values from my excel sheet, is that possible?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath of dropdown).sendKeys(ss.getRow(1).getCell(5).getStringCellValue());
```

This is not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check a few things. 

 1. Are you getting value from excel? If you print using the same method does that work?
 2. do you need sendKeys or select methods to select from drop-down?

Comment: String geo=ss.getRow(1).getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id=' GeographySelect']")).click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'"+geo+"')]")).click();it worked